# Redirecting all the traffic to index.php with unlimited parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, indexing, parameters

Let me introduce you to my problem. I am newbie to .htaccess... Untill my **.htaccess** worked pretty well, here is the code I was using for two url parameters (f.e. [www.page.com/en/articles](http://www.page.com/en/articles)):

```
# DISABLE CACHING

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires 0
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

But when I added third parameter like so (f.e. [www.page.com/en/articles/20](http://www.page.com/en/articles/20)):

```
...

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&url=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Then echo $_GET['lang'] returned "en" (thats OK) BUT echo $_GET['url'] returned "/articles/20" and $_GET['id'] didnt even exist (Thats NOT OK).

Can anyone please explain to me what in the world am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

My folder structure:

.htaccess

index.php

theme: pages | classes ...

assets: images | style | js ...

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [R=301,L]` - Is this the actual "working" code you were using?! It's difficult to see how this would have worked at all, unless you are perhaps making all your requests over HTTP (not HTTPS)?

Comment: Yes i it is actually working... As I said I am just a newbie in htaccess :)

Comment: So, are you making all your requests over HTTP-only then? It's just that your first rule has a _condition_ (`%{HTTPS} on`) that states that the rule will only apply to HTTPS requests. But if that rule is triggered then it's not possible that this could work since it "redirects" (not "rewrites") _everything_ to `index.php` (relative) which would result in a malformed redirect. (?!)

Answer (score 0):

You want to capture up to a `/` so try:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?lang=$1&url=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

But better maybe do the three cases notice no `[L]`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?lang=$1&url=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?lang=$1&url=$2&id=$3
```

To exclude a directory such as 'images` use a pass-thru.  If they are not in another directory you will have to match the type or extension.  Do this before the other rules:

```
RewriteRule ^images/.*$ - [PT]
```

From [Sammitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064767/sammitch), [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) will prevent the rewrite rules from triggering if an actual file by that name exists. There is also `-d` for directory, assuming a suitable `DirectoryIndex` configuration exists:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: Okay, this works... But i have another problem with this solution... All paths f.e. to styles and scripts are redirected also to index.php and are taken as page files... is there a way to exclude some ? (path to styles: www.page.com/assets/style/style.css)

Comment: Edited...  Depends on the structure, there should be lots of examples out there.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will prevent the rewrite rules from triggering if an actual file by that name exists. There is also `-d` for directory, assuming a suitable DirectoryIndex configuration exists. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Hey, I feel kinda lost because the pass-thru didnt work with ```RewriteRule ^assets/.*$ - [PT]```, i edited post with my folder structure..

Comment: You can also restrict the regex to avoid matching actual files (preferable to a filesystem check, which is relatively _expensive_). Actual files have a file extension, so if you are able to exclude a dot from the last path segment then you'll most probably avoid matching actual files. This regex should probably be made more restrictive anyway. I expect `lang` to be a 2 letter language code, `id` looks like a number and the `url` part could perhaps be restricted to `[\w-]` (upper and lowercase letters, digits, underscore and hyphen).

Comment: _Aside:_ "To exclude a directory such as 'images` use a pass-thru" - this is not really the correct use of a _passthrough_ (`PT` flag). When you rewrite to `-`, you're not actually "passing through" anything, so it's effectively ignored. It would be preferable to just use the `L` flag (which is _implied_ when `PT` is used). (Incidentally, the `PT` flag is really only relevant in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context since it is the default behaviour in `.htaccess`.)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing increasingly complicated regular expressions in apache configs, just bulk-rewrite everything to simply index.php and do the parsing in the application. You're already using index.php as a request router anyhow.

```php
// eg: /en/articles/20?other_query=vars&might=be_here
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$parts = explode('/', parse_url($uri)['path']);

var_dump($parts);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(2) "en"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "articles"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "20"
}
```

You got more/better tools to parse the URI in PHP.

This also has the bonus effect of making your application more easily portable as you don't need to reimplement as much config if you move to another HTTPd like nginx.

Comment: Yes you are right. I can do it in PHP but I just wanted to understand where is the problem in the .HTACCESS. If i dont find any solution for it, eventually i will use php and exploding :)

Comment: It's not necessarily Apache's issue, it's that you want open-ended repeating regex capture groups without having to write out each repetition which is something that regex in general is just not well suited for.